# Jquery read more button in infinite scroll script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Im making a website with user generated content. The content is text based and the most popular posts will be shown on the front page. Since the posts can be very long I wanted to add a read more button. The read more button works fine on the first 10 posts loaded, but won't work on the posts loaded with my infinite scroll script. The jquery pluginI used for read more is http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/.

Code for loading first 10 posts on the page:

```
<?php
if($sql1){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){
        echo '<div id="postlist">
        <div style="width:400px; font-size:24px;">' . $row['title'] . '</div>
        <article class="slide">' . nl2br($row['post']) . '</article>
        <span style="float:right; margin-right: 10px;">+ ' . $row['totalupvotes'] . ' | - ' . $row['totaldownvotes'] . '</span>
        <br />
        by <a style="font-size:18px;" href="profile.php?id=' . $row['submittedby'] . '">' . $row['submitteduser'] . '</a>
         at <span style="font-size:12px;">' . $row['added'] . '</span><span style="float:right; margin-right: 10px;">' . $row['totalcomments'] . ' comments</span>
         </div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Code for infinite scroll and read more plugin:

```
<script src="js/readmore.js"></script>
<script src="js/readmore.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loader").hide();
    var load = 0;
    var nbr = "<?php echo $nbr; ?>";
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
        {
            $("#loader").show();
            load++;
            if(load * 10 > nbr)
            {
                $("#messages").text("No more posts");
                $("#loader").hide();
            }
            else{
                $.post("php/newquery.php",{load:load},function(data){

                $("#contentwrapper").append(data);
                $("#loader").hide();
            });
            }
        }
    });
    $('article').readmore({
      maxHeight: 75,
      speed: 300
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the only code needed to get the read more button on article tags:

```
$('article').readmore({
          maxHeight: 75,
          speed: 300
        });
```

This is the newquery.php script for loading more posts:

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
require_once("config.php");
$load = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['load'])) * 10;

$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE totalupvotes < $trendmin AND deleted=0 ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT " . $load . ",10");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<div id="postlist">
        <div style="width:400px; font-size:24px;">' . $row['title'] . '</div>
        <article class="slide">' . nl2br($row['post']) . '</article>
        <span style="float:right; margin-right: 10px;">+ ' . $row['totalupvotes'] . ' | - ' . $row['totaldownvotes'] . '</span>
        <br />
        by <a style="font-size:18px;" href="profile.php?id=' . $row['submittedby'] . '">' . $row['submitteduser'] . '</a>
         at <span style="font-size:12px;">' . $row['added'] . '</span><span style="float:right; margin-right: 10px;">' . $row['totalcomments'] . ' comments</span>
         </div>';
}




?>
```

I'm guessing the problem has something to do with the infinite scroll script not really including the read more plugin. I'm not good with jquery at all so I just downloaded and modded the two scripts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your dynamically added `article`s are not bound as you are binding when the DOM is ready. Try adding `$('article').readmore({...` inside your `$.post()` success function so that it binds the new content.

Comment: Haha wow... I had actually tried what you said before posting here, but it turns out if I put the $('article').readmore() right after the $('#contentwrapper').append(data); it works! Thank you @Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. What you should do is probably run the `readmore()` on event-triggering:

put this ALSO inside the `window.scroll()` event:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
        {
            $("#loader").show();
            load++;
            if(load * 10 > nbr)
            {
                $("#messages").text("No more posts");
                $("#loader").hide();
            }
            else{
                $.post("php/newquery.php",{load:load},function(data){

                $("#contentwrapper").append(data);
                $("#loader").hide();
            });
            }
        }

    // HERE we also call readmore(), in addition to the first call on page load.
    $('article').readmore({
      maxHeight: 75,
      speed: 300
    });

    });
```

Comment: I had to put the $('article').readmore() right after the .append(data) line in addition to a $('article').readmore() tag outside the infinite scroll script. Thnx anyways :)